# need help using CSVHelper package in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I saw another example here on stackoverflow,
the code goes like this:

```
var csv = new CsvHelper( File.OpenWrite( "some-file.csv" ) );
csv.Writer.WriteRecords( myCustomObjectList );
```

However, I'm unable to instantiate CsvHelper class, as there isn't one, CsvHelper is a namespace.
Is there a way to get the above code working, or did I install something incorrectly?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that example is with an older version of the CsvHelper library. The API changed quite a bit between 1.x and 2.x, and there is no longer a `CsvHelper` class. You can instantiate the `CsvReader` and `CsvWriter` classes directly (or there's a `CsvFactory`), so the above code could look like this:

```
var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(new StreamWriter("some-file.csv"));
csvWriter.WriteRecords(myCustomObjectList)
```